# Configuration service in WCF?

Tags: wcf

Does WCF have an equivalent of "Configurator" service?

What I want to do is create a WCF Service that will handle configuration for my whole application. So things like defaults for various components and such.

So, something like this:

[image]

My **question** is: does WCF something like this already?

I know how to write this, but before I do, I wanted to see if perhaps I was re-doing something that's already available.

*NOTE*: This is perhaps confusing terminology, as WCF uses the word *configuration* to mean, for example, configuration of WCF service endpoints and bindings, through config files or programmatically. I don't mean that. I mean the actual configuration of the application itself.

Comment: Actual configuration of a .NET application is usually done through the .NET configuration system, usually using XML configuration files. Note that the system can be extended.

Comment: I'll have to check it out, thanks! I want it to be a service level property, accessible and changeable at runtime, by any service and not a static artifact. But maybe .NET configuration system allows for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WCF is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) a framework for building distributed / service-oriented applications with .NET, there is nothing "extra" in WCF (beyond what's already in .NET, like the configuration system mentioned in comments) to manage application settings. As far as I know there's no "Configurator Service" in WCF itself.

The basic design you've drawn is certainly possible, you can create the "Configuration Service" with WCF, but WCF will only offer you bits for the framework and infrastructure on the service-oriented side of things. The actual logic will be in your service and its operations, which you'll have to code yourself (though you could use a different framework or boilerplate code for that logic).

Answer (score 0):

It's not built in but, as you say, you can roll your own.

I've seen it done in a demo on Channel9 (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/MID402 @ the halfway mark) where the demonstrator stored configs in a database and all clients and servers pulled down their config. Looks useful for a large scale operations but probably not worth it if you just have a few clients/servers.

Here's a PowerPoint (http://media.ch9.ms/teched/na/2011/ppt/MID402.pptx) but you get some detail from the video.